# Square wave frequency multiplier

Tags: oscillator, frequency, pll

Where can I find a frequency multiplier circuit or IC that can multiply the frequency of a square wave or a sine wave by four?

The input frequency can be from 100Hz to 1MHz, corresponding to an output range of 400Hz to 4MHz.

Comment: Multiplying a square wave by 4 can be done with a phase locked loop. Multiplying a sinewave by 4 needs a different approach so, if you want your circuit to seamlessly work with both square waves and sinewaves you might be  out of luck. Your frequency range (100 Hz to 1 MHz) also calls for extensive circuitry and not something you can just cobble together in an afternoon. Maybe about 3 days design work, about 3 days build work and about 5 days test and modify work. Are you prepared to do that or, do you want to explain what you are actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

A phase-locked loop easily can multiply an input signal by 4x.  The problem is having loop dynamics that are stable over a 10:1 frequency range.  There is another way.

A frequency-to-voltage converter driving a voltage-to-frequency converter is an all electronic version of a motor-generator set.  Other names for the circuits are an FM discriminator followed by a voltage-controlled oscillator, or VCO.  With careful component selection, this approach can handle the frequency range, do fractional conversions, etc.

As better analog components became available in the 80's, the trade magazines often had design articles on the two function blocks and the overall approach.  Jim Williams was famous for long applications articles on things like this, and all of his material is available online.

This approach does not have the bolted-down accuracy of something with a digital counter in the middle of it.  It needs calibration, has temperature effects, and it has a settling time to recover from step changes in the input frequency. We do not have nearly enough information to address how these aspects would affect your application.  On the plus side, it is absolutely monotonic, meaning it cannot lock onto an incorrect multiple (harmonic).

Answer (score 1):

> The input frequency can be from 100Hz to 1MHz, corresponding to an output range of 400Hz to 4MHz.

That's quite a large range. More than an octave, to be exact, so that classical "square the signal and filter out anything but the harmonic you want" won't work (for the sine wave; squaring a squaring a square wave makes no sense, you'd just filter out the harmonic you want that it already has).

Only way I can think off right now is a control loop that makes sure some controllable oscillator has four periods where your input clock has one.

That's a PLL. Andy says (in the comment beneath your question) that you can not use a PLL to synthesize a sine wave four times the frequency of its input, but I think what he means is that that would require a phase error detector that is significantly more complex than what you'll usually find in a PLL.

Since your frequency range is rather low, and you don't specify any acceptable jitter, I guess you don't care too much about frequency stability, phase noise or control loop dynamics. So, get a cheap microcontroller eval board (the STM32 Nucleo boards are popular, and even the cheapest ones have a microcontroller that would run fast enough), make sure your input signal is amplified and cleaned up enough to have reliable sharp upwards edge every period, set up the timer unit in your microcontroller to count the length of the period, use that value (quite possibly directly via DMA!), divided by four (i.e. right shift by 2 bit positions, or let that second timer run at four times the clock rate) as period in a second timer unit for a PWM output, and be done with it.

For the frequencies towards your upper end, your resolution of course will be worse. There's ways around that, using external VCOs, a filtered output that you dither and some control loop smarts, but, again, you're not posting any requirements, so I'll assume there are none that rule out the simpler approach of doing this using only one timer unit as frequency counter, and one as PWM synthesizer.

As usual, microcontrollers are application-specific ICs for control jobs, and yours is a control job, so microcontrollers are the IC you need.

---

There's plenty of frequency synthesizer ICs out there, but they won't work at 100 Hz.

---

Instead of counting periods, you could actually ADC-convert your signal and estimate the frequency from that, which would give you a frequency estimate *precision* that is unlimited by sampling rate (only limited by SNR). You could then synthesize four times that frequency (e.g. using DDS, CORDICs, plain old trigonometric function estimations from your favourite math) at arbitrary precision and send it to a DAC (again, frequency precision only limited by the precision of your sine wave synthesis and quantization).

That's a nice approach, as it gives you loads of freedom, but it requires an ADC running at > 2 MHz, frequency estimation (e.g. through estimation with ESPRIT or Max. Entropy spectral estimation). Might be doable on higher-end microcontrollers, especially since these not only integrate ADCs but also DACs, but is out of reach for lower-end microcontrollers.

Comment: I'm not sure I recognize your statement about what I said or what you disagree with. The problem might be the ambiguity in your sentence i.e. `I don't think you can only use one to double your frequency` might mean two things i.e. you need more than one to double the frequency or i.e.  using one device gives other problems. Just trying to help out. Nothing against your English of course dear boy.

Comment: hey, hope I don't suffer or lead to misunderstandings :) I think it might really be phrased badly, let me change that